# ASP.NET instantiating regex within a static method and thread safety

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, .net-4.0, thread-safety

Taken the following class that is part of a ASP.NET HttpModule (and taken that I know about regex and html, I don't have a choice in this one though):

```
sealed internal class RegexUtility
{
    public static Regex RadioButton { get; private set; }

    static RegexUtility()
    {
       RadioButton = new Regex(@"<input.*type=.?radio.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
}
```

I'm concerned about thread safety with this code. As the regex is readonly I know I don't have to worry about modification once the it's in memory. I'm worried about the instantiation itself however, should I lock it in the constructor? An educated guess would suggest that the code below would be thread safe. My thinking is that two threads might try and instantiate it at the same time, hence the need for the lock. However, as this is static, and as far as I know there is only one instance of the application in the IIS app pool (correct?) then perhaps it's not something I need to worry about.

```
sealed internal class RegexUtility
{
    public static Lazy<Regex> RadioButton { get; private set; }

    static RegexUtility()
    {
        RadioButton = new Lazy<Regex>(() => new Regex(@"<input.*type=.?radio.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled));
    }
}
```

Would somebody cast a more knowledgeable light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) is guaranteed to only run once, so your first snippet should be fine.

From section 17.11 of the [ECMA C# Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm):

> The static constructor for a non-generic class executes at most once
>   in a given application domain. The static constructor for a generic
>   class declaration executes at most once for each closed constructed
>   type constructed from the class declaration.

Comment: Link to the spec is a very helpful addition to your answer, I shall spend many hours pouring over that document now.

Comment: @Phil: Be aware that the ECMA spec is almost 10 years old now, although it's still useful as a "baseline" reference. The [Microsoft spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) includes all the more recent changes to the language not included in the ECMA version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also define a parameter-free constructor for better safety.
Also, it is not a bad idea to use .Net 4.0 `System.Lazy` type which guarantees thread-safe lazy-construction here.

```
    public class RegexUtility
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<RegexUtility> _instance
            = new Lazy<RegexUtility>(() => new RegexUtility());

        private static Lazy<Regex> _radioButton = new Lazy<Regex>(() => new Regex(@"<input.*type=.?radio.*?>"));
        public static Regex RadioButton
        {
            get
            {
                return _radioButton.Value;
            }
        }

        // private to prevent direct instantiation.
        private RegexUtility()
        {
        }

        // accessor for instance
        public static RegexUtility Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

When using the class, you will work with the `Regex` object as if it were a regular static property:

```
   var regex = RegexUtility.RadioButton;
```

Please see [this page](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx) with some more explanations.

Comment: Does the parameter free constructor provide better safety by being private? If so that's omitted from my code by mistake - nice catch. But from LukeH's post it seems I don't need to use lazy as the code is already thread safe. Or is there a chance that two threads will indeed try to instantiate the regex at the same time?

Comment: OR(!) is it that your approach means that construction will always be lazy?

Comment: Lazy construction provides better control over how many threads at a time can access the lazily instantiated object. Perhaps, best is to set "isThreadSafe" option in a `Lazy<Regex>` declaration to `false`, so that each thread could access the object once at a time. The point is that the object itself, even if created with thread safe option, is still not automatically protected. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.